# What is wrong with my Select so that my case works again

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Hi my select here is not working. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my syntax? I would like to get 3 columns with different results from the name, upper,lower and initcap but when the name dr. has then only the next 3 letters are given as upper.

```
select mitarbeitername,
    case 
    when regexp_like(mitarbeitername, '^Dr.*')  then  upper(substr(mitarbeitername,4))
    else upper(substr(mitarbeitername, 1,3))
     , lower(substr(mitarbeitername, 1,3) )
     , initcap(substr(mitarbeitername, 1,3)) 
    end Name   
from mitarbeiter;
```

Comment: See [`CASE` expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html). Entire case expression should evaluate to a value, so all parts (`then` or `else`) of it should be expressions. `expr, expr, expr` is not an expression because it is not scalar (in terms of any datatype). Please describe what you expect `else` branch to do.

Comment: Hi - what does “not working” mean? Does it produce an error and what is the error message? Does it not produce the expected result - in which case please provide sample data, the result it is giving and the result you want? Please update your question with additional information

Comment: the else branch is not OK. How come that you have there 3 different expressions separated by comma: upper(substr(mitarbeitername, 1,3)), lower(substr(mitarbeitername, 1,3) ), initcap(substr(mitarbeitername, 1,3)) ? You should have only one expression on each branch of the case. Or is it that you mas have several when, and two of those three expressions should be on two different branches, while the third on else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to get 3 columns with different results from the name, upper, lower and initcap but when the name dr. has then only the next 3 letters are given as upper.

A `CASE` expression outputs a single scalar value; it **cannot** output three values. If want three values then use three `CASE` expressions:

```sql
SELECT mitarbeitername,
       CASE
       WHEN mitarbeitername LIKE 'Dr.%')
       THEN UPPER(SUBSTR(mitarbeitername,4))
       ELSE UPPER(SUBSTR(mitarbeitername, 1,3))
       END AS upper_name,
       CASE
       WHEN mitarbeitername LIKE 'Dr.%')
       THEN NULL
       ELSE LOWER(SUBSTR(mitarbeitername, 1,3))
       END AS lower_name,
       CASE
       WHEN mitarbeitername LIKE 'Dr.%')
       THEN NULL
       ELSE INITCAP(SUBSTR(mitarbeitername, 1,3))
       END AS initcap_name
FROM   mitarbeiter;
```

*Note: You do not need to use regular expressions to match string starting with `Dr`; you can perform a simple string comparison using `LIKE`, which will be much faster. If you did want to use regular expressions then you want the pattern `^Dr\.` or `^Dr\..*` as an unescaped `.` will match any character.*